# User submitted iframes - what to watch out for?

Tags: injection, iframe

I'm building a part of a site where users can embed Youtube videos into their profile. I'm planning to have them get the embed iframe from Youtube directly, and submit that to our server. We're then responsible for rendering it.

For completeness, a typical such iframe would look like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZK7ih4V0erc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Of course, it would be *bad* to just take whatever HTML the user provides and render it verbatim. My question is: How much effort should I go to to verify this iframe is what I expect?

My approach at the moment is to parse whatever HTML they provide, and:

1. Verify that the fragment is an iframe,
2. Verify that the src attribute comes from Youtube.

Is there anything beyond this that I should be watching out for? I'm okay with them specifying a youtube video incorrectly (i.e. giving the ID for a video that doesn't exist).

Comment: Why not just take the Youtube ID or extract the ID from src, discard their iframe, and build your own?

Comment: Taking the Youtube ID as input was my first idea, and the counter was that users might find it unnecessarily counterintuitive (i.e. if we say "follow these instructions from Youtube help", then nobody can get frustrated with us if our explanation turns out not to be clear enough).

Taking the ID from src is appealing - I was originally hoping not to have to do detailed parsing of the URL (since the more complex the parse is, the more likely you are to get it wrong and present confusing errors). But that is probably equally hard as verifying the src.

Comment: I just have them submit the shareURL.  I store the whole URL, but parse out the id and validate/filter it.  I rebuild the entire tag from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to validate *every* part of the input very *strictly*: input format, tag name, tag format, all attribute names, all attribute values. A single mistake in the validation process might leave you vulnerable to XSS. In your steps for verifying the input you only mentioned a check on the tag name (iframe) and a check on the `src` attribute. That's not enough because you would have at least to make sure there are no attributes related to JavaScript events: onload, onmouseover, onclick, etc. There are a lot of them. A tag like this would execute JavaScript when it's loaded for example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com" onload="alert('xss')">
```

Then maybe the `style` attribute could in some cases become dangerous, maybe by loading external URLs with some trick like `style="background:url(...)"`. I have seen some of such tricks listed in some XSS cheatsheets, and while they might only work in some browsers or in some restricted cases, the fact that such tricks exist tells me that you had better watch out. Google "XSS cheatsheet" and take a look at some examples if you want to see some "scary" examples of how attackers can be "creative" when trying to circumvent filters and rules. And then there might be other attributes that could be used to cause trouble, or maybe new risky attributes will be added to the HTML standard in the future, who knows? We all know that blacklists are not considered secure, and you should validate everything with a whitelist. But at this point it's probably going to be a lot of work for nothing.

All this is probably not worth it for your purposes, and it's easier to provide your own predefined safe iframe tag. You probably only need the ID of the video, all the rest of the information is unnecessary and potentially dangerous. So you could extract the ID of the video, validate it, and then build your own iframe tag safely on the server side.

I read that you are worried about advanced parsing, but you don't need any advanced parsing for your simple purpose. For example, the following regex should be enough to match the video ID in an iframe, no matter what the other arguments are, and even if the tag is malformed (you don't really care if it's a perfectly valid iframe tag, all you care about is the intention of the user to embed a youtube video with an iframe).

```
/<iframe [^<>]+src="https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)"[^<>]+>/
```

Of course you can use an HTML parsing library for this purpose too. You might need to check if other characters are possible in the video ID, because I'm not sure if dots are also allowed, for example. You don't need a separate step for validating the video ID, because it's already validated by the regex (valid IDs can only contain the specified characters). Then you need to remove the iframe tag from the user input, and replace it with your safe tag. Your safe tag will just be static HTML where you only replace the video ID with the one provided by the user. For example, in PHP it could be something like this:

```
echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' .
     htmlspecialchars($matched_video_ID, ENT_QUOTES) .
     ' frameborder="0" allow="..." allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

Note that I used `htmlspecialchars` (or you could use `urlencode` too) even though it was not necessary, because the video ID was validated and can only contain safe characters. I sanitized the variable anyway because I think it should be a habit to do so, no matter if at the moment such a weakness would not be exploitable.

**A final warning**

I'm not sure where the user is going to put that iframe, and I'm not sure if the user is already allowed to use other HTML tags. If the iframe is the only tag they can use, and that iframe is going to be embedded among other text, then you need to make sure the user won't try to use other tags anywhere else. In other words, special characters like `<>&` will need to be encoded everywhere in input coming from the user... except that you need to keep the iframe. I'm not sure how you are going to do this. You could remove the iframe code at first, sanitize the output by encoding the special characters, and then only add the iframe back again at the end. Or you could try out something like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) if your needs become a little too complex.

Comment: Thanks! I think this confirms that the most reasonable approach is to construct a safe iframe myself. I think I mis-stated my worry about parsing. I have plenty of HTML/URL parsing libraries available to me, but was put off by the possible variants of valid youtube URLs (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/how-do-i-get-the-youtube-video-id-from=-a-url)).

However, I think it is probably good enough to just match the youtube.com/embed/ID form, in which case it is not so hard.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, could you explain what specific XSS threats do you have in mind in this case? Supposing the checks I suggested in the OP were carried out properly, are there other likely sources of danger? This is partly for my own education, and partly to convince someone on my team who is not entirely convinced of the need to build the tag from scratch.

Comment: @preferred_anon, I edited my answer to add some stuff at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! For your curiosity: other content that the users are allowed to submit is either plain text or a small subset of "formatted plain text" (precisely, the default Rails `sanitize` function applied to an HTML fragment, so things like bold tags, links etc.). The iframe input box itself is meant to be just that: you copy the "share" link directly from youtube and submit that by itself.